# How to Install angular js in Yocto

Tags: angularjs, npm-install, yocto, imx8

I have tried below names for angularjs inside conf/local.conf file, but that package is not getting installed.

1. `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " angular-js"`
2. `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " angularjs"`

Is the packeage name is different? How can I install AngularJs in yocto?.

Comment: I don't know anything about yocto, but the package name on npm is `angular`

Comment: I couldn't find `anguar-js` recipe in neither of the public meta-layers. Where are you getting it from?

Answer (score 0):

You need a need a recipe to install a package this way. Do you have a recipe someone else has written, or have you written one your self.
There are a couple recipes that others have written, but none match the name you are using. Here is a link that will search for packges named angular [link](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/recipes/?q=angular).

I would suggest you spend more time getting familiar with recipes, yocto, and bitbake. Checkout the [users manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html) for a basic understanding of bitbake.